# PHP multiple identical variables on page

Tags: php, variables, include, echo

I have a page on a website I am building, that has a row of 4 div blocks that each link to the page they grab information from.

So in context, I have **4 div blocks** with a Country name, country img, country desk limited to 100 characters and a 'read more' button.. All the information of this div is taken from a **country_name.php** file.

BUT, I have **4 different blocks** for each different country. So each country has its own country_name.php file with the **same variables**, just different values.

My questions is, is there a way to **include each of the 4 php files** so I can include the variables on my page to echo the information, but as the variable names for each country are the same, will I have to start and stop the php include. After the stop point, no more variables from that php file will be outputted.

If this is the solution, how?! I have no idea how to do this or the best way to approach this problem? Can anyone help me out here?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to include them at once?

Comment: Yes, all the php files will be loaded onto the page so I can print their variables in the relevant divs

Comment: did you think of multiple array to store the variables?

Comment: Do you mean a multidimensional array? :S I am not brilliant with php or I wouldn't be in this situation haha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to create an array of country names representing your file names

ie:

```
$countries = array(
  "united_kingdom", 
  "south_korea", ...);
```

then

```
$country_values = array();

foreach($countries as $country)
{
  include $country . ".php";
  $country_values[$country] = array($countryName, $desc);
}
```

and then you can access your data like

```
foreach($countries as $your_desired_country)
{
  //$your_desired_country = "south_korea";
  list($countryName, $desc) = $country_values[$your_desired_country];
  echo "<div>Country name: $countryName</div>";
  echo "<div>Description: $desc</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter for your answer above. So just to understand properly, where you said $your_country_values_here, ...
That is to put all the variables from the country.php files right? Is that correct?

and then in my div where I want to echo two variables for example $countryName and $desc.
How would I do this using your method??

Comment: Please check the edited reply. You are correct, at first, you will pull all country values into multidimensional array and then you can access them anywhere.

Comment: Ha, okay.. so! I have tried implementing this into my code but I have another query. Your answer is probably right, but in terms of including my php files. On my page, I include ALL of the country.php files I want to include on the page using the standard include();. THEN beneath that, I create my array using the names of the php files I have included?

Can I also check I understand the php for the foreach function you have outlined. That statement is filtering the countries and isolating the one country in my array I want to use so I can use it's variables only and no others?

Comment: Luke, use first and second code statement in my example to get values about your countries from all files you have. Than, if you don't want to foreach trought all country values, you can access them one by one like `$south_korea_values = $country_values['south_korea']; list($sk_countryName, $sk_desc) = $south_korea_values;`  simple like that

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I would just name my variable differently in the 4 php files and include them.

Comment: That is an option, but the reality is.. 4 php was for example purposes. It is really around 60 files of variables. Rather not uniquely name all of these files and alter EVERY page they are on